# How to count occurances of a character in file?

Tags: java, file

I want to print no. of a, b, c,etc... Special characters, vowels, consonants in file using Java. how to do that?

Comment: How far have you tried ?

Comment: If this is homework, please _tag_ it as homework, so would-be helpers know how best to help.  If not homework, please edit your question to explain in what context, for what "actual application" purpose you need this computation -- again, having context helps us to help you, so, _please_, **do** supply context with your questions -- it's in everybody's best interest!

Answer (score 2):

1. create `map <char, int>`
2. read file char by char.
3. if char in map -> map.put(map.get(char)+1) else map.put(char, 1)

Comment: There is no such thing as a `Map <char, int>`. It would have to be a map of wrapper types: `Map <Character, Integer>`

Comment: I know. I just don't really want to chew everything for topic-starter, because it really looks like homework. Anyway, it is very basic thing, and if topic-starter doesn't know them, i'd recommend to spend some time on learning basics.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the file
2. Go through the file character by character.
3. If the current char matches the char you want,increment the counter by one
4. Detect end of file (EOF) and print the counter value.

Read [File Handling](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/java103/java103.html) , [InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

Give it a try and if you are stuck at something specific,come back with the specific question.